# Selenium WebDriver not able to find elements which are not present in the Page Source but present in HTML when seen through Developer Tools

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am using Selenium Web Driver HtmlUnitDriver for searching elements on a web page. 
I am able to search only those elements that are visible in the Page Source. 
However I can see these elements details using the Internet Explorer Developer Tools (F12).
When I use these details (id/name/XPath) using Selenium, it throws a `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`.
The code I have written is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(){
            @Override
            protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {

                DefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();
                credentialsProvider.addNTLMCredentials("username", "password", null, -1, "localhost", "domain");
                client.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                return client;
            }
        };

        driver.get("URL");

        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ppm_timesheet")));

    }
```

PAGE SOURCE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="application-name" content="CONTENT"/>
    <meta name="upk-namespace" content="en"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="ui/uitk/images/shortcut.ico"/>
    <title>
      Title
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/uitk/css/min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/ext/ext.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    require( {baseUrl: "ui"},[ "uif/js/main.min" ] );
    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ppm">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I search  the element "ppm", it is successful which is present in page source. 
When I search the element "ppm_timesheet" I am getting following exception maybe because this element is not present in the page source.
But when I press F12 in Internet Explorer and select this element in developer tools, this element is present there in HTML:

```
<button title="Time" class="class" id="ppm_timesheet" type="submit" jQuery171013988872804261454="13" alt="Time">
```

The full exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds
Build info: version: '2.8.0', revision: '14056', time: '2011-10-06 12:41:26'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:188)
    at com.auto.Automation.main(Automation.java:32)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: ppm_timesheet
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.8.0', revision: '14056', time: '2011-10-06 12:41:26'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementById(HtmlUnitDriver.java:685)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:210)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:969)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:396)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:289)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:287)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$3.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$3.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:173)
```

I have read that some elements are generated on the client side and not seen in view source. But does that imply that we cannot access those elements at all which are not in View Source.

I have already tried waiting for the element to load for 30 seconds. But still I am getting the same error.

Please provide your inputs as I have googled a lot and not able to figure this out.

Comment: Are the elements contained in a `frame` or `iframe`?

Comment: How can i verify that ? I tried searching the Page source for iframe but could not find anything

Comment: Hi Guys !! Please suggest something. I am badly stuck with this. Have tried all the available solutions from similar threads but none is working.

Comment: There isn't a link that we could use to examine the problem.  There's no code showing what you have attempted.  There's no HTML showing the problem.  In short, you've asked us to solve a problem without providing any resources to help us.

Comment: Hi Richard, I have edited the question providing the details. Being confidential I cannnot share the html or screenshots.
Let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: What happens if you use a different driver implementation? We had a case where HtmlUnit was not powerful enough to support certain JavaScript constructs.

Comment: Actually I am bulding a tool for automation, not using Selenium for Testing. So i wud just run a java program which will automatically login to the url and do the required functionalities.
I think for other webdrivers, Browser opens which i dont want

Comment: Ok, in this case I simply wouldn't use WebDriver at all. Just use HtmlUnit or even just an HTTPClient directly.

Comment: I just tried creating instance of HTMLUnitDriver instead of WebDriver reference. I am again getting the same exception :(

Comment: We could help you more if you would provide us at least some DOM examples...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the element you are looking for is not in the page source should not be a problem. The WebDriver API was [introduced to explicitly add support for dynamic pages](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#how-does-webdriver-drive-the-browser-compared-to-selenium-rc), e.g. where elements are added via JavaScript.

However it is not sufficient that an element is in the DOM, but the element also needs to be visible. WebDriver means to only allow interactions which also a user could do, so if an element is not visible, you should e.g. not be able to click on it via WebDriver.

Comment: The element is visible. I am able to see the html for that using IE developer tools. I click on the link and i can see the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Scenario description There can be one reason
 **dynamically loading** of content.
in this scenario selenium code runs faster while html(java script / framework) code at browser end take time to load dynamic data from server .
so use waitdriver to make selenium driver wait until dynamic data loads and append to DOM

`````
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(xpathOfElement));````
`````